# Javascript/JQuery populate array many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Okay, So I'm using tampermonkey/greasemonkey to load and save data for userscripts using `GM_getValue/setValue`

At one point, I had stored 7000 objects into one of these arrays, and proceeded to output it via a `window.open` and `$(disp.document.body).text` and a subsequent `.join` call on the array. This allowed me to copy all 7000 objects strings into a normal .txt file in notepad.

However, my issue comes from this: I cleared the original array of 7000 objects, but I want to restore all of these back into the array; without having to either manually do `array[0] = "foo"` and `array [1] = "bar"` etc.

I was thinking that maybe I could open up a new window, dump all 7000 strings into it, and then somehow have a button to parse that window? just not sure how

I'm wondering what's the most efficient/easiest way to manually populate an array from an outside source (notepad) into javascript arrays.

Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: Paste the text into a spreadhseet and then copy the cells and paste into  https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/ Otherwise is quite easy to use `split('\n')` in javascript to convert lines to array

Comment: How are the values in your text file separated?

Comment: Just by new line. So after using that website, I would then have to import it somehow into greasemonkey?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using String.protype.split()?

```
arr = textFromFile.split(/\n|\r/);
```